# Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined in Joomla 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, joomla3.2

I just updated my site to the latest Joomla version 3.2.1 from 3.2. I am using an Article Slider module. All of a sudden the module is throwing the following console errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined    slider.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function    index.php:253
```

The script files are loaded as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">    </script>
<script src="/adventure/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/media/system/js/tabs-state.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/modules/mod_klixo_articles_slider/assets/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/adventure/modules/mod_klixo_articles_slider/assets/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code that calls the jQuery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (typeof (jQuery) === 'undefined') {
        jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var KSlideShow = new klSlider({
            fx: '<?php echo $transitionList; ?>',
            randomizeEffects: '<?php echo $randomizeEffects; ?>',
            timeout: <?php echo $timer_speed; ?>,
            speed: <?php echo $slideshow_speed; ?>,
            next: '#next<?php echo $module->id; ?>',
            prev: '#prev<?php echo $module->id; ?>',
            pause: <?php echo ($pause) ? 1 : 0; ?>,
            divId: <?php echo $module->id; ?>,
            autoPlay: <?php echo $auto_play; ?>,
            startingSlide: 0,
            moduleID: '<?php echo $module->id; ?>',
            showReadmore: <?php echo $show_readmore ?>,
            slidesautoHeight: <?php echo $css_Scaling ?>
        });
        KSlideShow.sliderStart();

<?php if ($css_Scaling == 1) { ?>
            KSlideShow.resize();
<?php }
?>
    });

</script>
```

The slider was working fine some while ago, and suddenly these errors appeared. How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Check if jquery js file is actually loading.

Comment: @Alfabravo.. I have listed the files that are being loaded. Apart from these, some other script files of the template are also loaded.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Check in your browser using dev tools that the files are actually loaded.

Comment: @Alfabravo.. the above file list I have copied from Inspect Element. I have also checked the resources tab. jquery.min.js is loaded and not jquery.js.